Format Multienumeration Data for Pivot Table
I'm relatively new to excel pivot tables, and I'm trying to figure out how exactly to format my raw data dump from an external application, so that when I push the data into excel for analysis, I can build different pivot tables/graphs from the same dataset, or minimize the amount of formatting I need to perform everytime this data dump occurs.
Currently, I have a list of items (each represented by a row) that have multiple enumerated values for certain columns. For instance, the color column could be "red" or "red, blue, black", and an animal column could be "dog" or "dog, parrot".



Element ID
Color
Animal
State




1
Red, Blue, Black
Dog, Parrot
KS


2
Red, Black
Dog, Cat
NY


3
Blue
Parrot
KS



And I'm trying to create a pivot table that has the different animals as the rows, the different colors as the columns, and the values being the counts of products (rows in my original dataset) which have that color/animal combination.




Red
Blue
Black




Dog
2
1
2


Cat
1
0
1


Parrot
1
2
1



As far as I can tell from my research, I don't think there's a way to create the above pivot data with my raw data formatted the way I have above, regardless of the delimiter I use, but please share if this is incorrect.
I understand that one way to format the data to allow me to perform this analysis is to split the multiple enumeration columns into separate lines, say three distinct rows/entries in my raw data for the "red, blue, black" enumerations in the color column, and then do the same thing with all other multi-enumerated columns.



Element ID
Color
Animal




1
Red
Dog


1
Blue
Dog


1
Black
Dog


1
Red
Parrot


1
Blue
Parrot


1
Black
Parrot



The problem with that is that then when I use the same raw dataset to generate pivot tables for counting properties other than color (say State vs Animal), the same item that has now been split into multiple rows and is now counted multiple times, which I do not want.
The other solution I considered is to take the single set of raw data I have, and create different versions of it on different sheets that are then ingested by different pivot tables. So for instance, when I'm counting against the color property I'll use a table that splits my "red, blue, black" entry out into three distinct rows, but when I'm not counting against color, I'll use a table on a different sheet that only has one row.
I know that I can create the analysis pivot table above without pivot tables using a matrix of countifs formulas, but I'm trying to stick with pivot tables if possible, as they're just a lot more accessible and easier to manage.
I feel like I'm missing something with pivot tables, as I'm guessing there's a much more elegant solution that I'm just not aware of. Any help would be appreciated.

Post few of your sample data as text table and then show your desired output.

Thanks for the reply! I've updated my original post with some examples tables. Let me know if it's still unclear what I'm asking.

Using Power Query we could keep only one source (data dump table) along with a mapped second table that is automatically updated:

Import the first data dump into Power Query - in the example I've imported it from Table1 (after importing into Excel and creating table)

Create a new query by referencing this table (so any updates to Table1 will be automatically reflected in the new one.)

Enter following in the Advanced Editor to split and trim the columns


let
  Source = Table1,
  removedState = Table.RemoveColumns(Source, {"State"}),
  splitColorIntoRows = Table.ExpandListColumn(
    Table.TransformColumns(
      Table.TransformColumnTypes(removedState, {{"Color", type text}}),
      {
        {
          "Color",
          Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(","),
          let
            itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]
          in
            type {itemType}
        }
      }
    ),
    "Color"
  ),
  splitAnimalIntoRows = Table.ExpandListColumn(
    Table.TransformColumns(
      Table.TransformColumnTypes(splitColorIntoRows, {{"Animal", type text}}),
      {
        {
          "Animal",
          Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(","),
          let
            itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]
          in
            type {itemType}
        }
      }
    ),
    "Animal"
  ),
  trimmedCols = Table.TransformColumns(
    splitAnimalIntoRows,
    {
      {"Color", each Text.Trim(_), type nullable text},
      {"Animal", each Text.Trim(_), type nullable text}
    }
  )
in
  trimmedCols


Rename the table, for example tbColorAndAnimal
Close and load into Excel


Use this table as the basis for pivot table for Color and Animal and use the first one for other summaries.
Whenever the data changes, click on Refresh under Data tab to refresh results from Power Query and pivot tables:

